# How do you use an event listener in markers whose event toggles between two functions when listened to?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

I have this section of code which works well:

```
marker.addListener('click', function(){
    showInfo(marker, content);
});
marker.addListener('dblclick', function(){
    hideInfo();
});
```

I’m using two event listeners, one listens to ‘click’ and the other listens to ‘dblclick’. However, I only want to use just one event listener that listens to ‘click’ and achieve the same results. How can I toggle between `showInfo()` and `hideInfo()` functions by using just one event ‘click’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a global variable to determine whether the info is visible or hidden.

```
...
var isInfoVisible;
...
```

then

```
marker.addListener('click', function(){
    if (isInfoVisible){
        isInfoVisible = false;
        hideInfo();
    } else {
        isInfoVisible = true;
        showInfo(marker, content);
    }       
});
```

OR:

if you use infowindow you can check if it is attached to the map.

```
marker.addListener('click', function(){
    if (infowindow.map != null){
        infowindow.close();
    } else {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }       
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oxh0gq5w/